# Can you help me with my codes about methoding?

Tags: java

I need some help with my homework, so basically we need to create a code in which we input 10 numbers in an array, then search the array if my inputted number is there, most of the code is done. I just need to method the loop for searching if the inputted number is in the array Thanks for the help!!!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n, x, flag = 0, i = 0;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a[] = new int[10];
    System.out.println("Enter all the values:");
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    System.out.print("Value "+(i+1)+": ");
        a[i] = s.nextInt();

    }

    System.out.print("Enter the value you want to find: ");
    x = s.nextInt();

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == x)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            flag = 0;
        }

    }
    if(flag == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("The value "+x+" is found at index "+(i+1));
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("The value "+x+" is found at index "+(-1));
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you already have the search, what is the problem with what you have?

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) { }` this is a method. You can easily create a a new method using the same syntax for your requirement.

Comment: I need to method the way to search the value inputted, I don't have much experience in methods sorry

Comment: `public static int findInArray(int[] numbers, int toFind) {....}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n, x, flag = 0, i = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a[] = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter all the values:");
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Value "+(i+1)+": ");
            a[i] = s.nextInt();

        }

        System.out.print("Enter the value you want to find: ");
        x = s.nextInt();

        i = find(a, 10, x);
        if(i != -1)
        {
            System.out.println("The value "+x+" is found at index "+(i+1));
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("The value "+x+" is found at index "+(-1));
        }
    }

    private static int find(int a[],int n, int x) {
            int i, flag = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] == x)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                flag = 0;
            }

        }
        if(flag == 1) {
            return i;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Main {
    public static int findIndexOfNumber(int numberToSearch, int[] numbers) {
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
            if(numbers[i]==numberToSearch) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, x, flag = 0, i = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a[] = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter all the values:");
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print("Value "+(i+1)+": ");
            a[i] = s.nextInt();

        }

        System.out.print("Enter the value you want to find: ");
        x = s.nextInt();
        flag = findIndexOfNumber(x, a);
        System.out.println("The value "+x+" is found at index "+flag);
    }
}
```

You can try this also